# Is it possible to reuse parts of a LINQ to Entities select statement?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

When using LINQ to Entities, is there a way to reuse a block of a select statment in other select stements?  
For example, in the below code, I'm using LINQ to select a customer device object from my database.  I also select a related Model object from a table that is joined to the customer devices table.

```
            list = context.PTT_CUSTOMER_DEVICES
                .Include(...)
                .Select(d => new CustomerDevice
                {
                    customerAssetTag = d.CustomerAssetTag,
                    customerDeviceID = d.CustomerDeviceID,
                    //This section is used in several LINQ statements throughout the application.
                    Model = new Model()
                    {
                        ModelID = d.PTS_MODELS.ModelID,
                        Name = d.PTS_MODELS.Name,
                        Make = new Make()
                        {
                            MakeID = d.PTS_MODELS.PTS_MAKES.MakeID,
                            Name = d.PTS_MODELS.PTS_MAKES.Name
                        }
                    }
                 })...
```

There are, however, other objects in the database that also reference the Model table.  In my select statements for those other tables, I basically copied the same Model = new Model() code to a select statement for those different tables.  
What I'm wondering is, is it possible to store and reuse that block of code in multiple selects?  Possibly using an extension method?

Comment: you're passing a lambda to that Select, you can store that in a variable and reuse. You can also save the Model part into a function and pass everything you need to it as arguments, you can also create a map between type of your variable `d` and `CustomerDevice` or `Model` via Automapper or similar tool and map with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to `Func<>`s, you can also make use of extension methods to reuse the conversions between your entity types to and other POCOs.

```cs
public static IQueryable<CustomerDevice> ToCustomerDevice(this IQueryable<PTT_CUSTOMER_DEVICES> devices)
{
    return devices.Select(d => new CustomerDevice
    {
        customerAssetTag = d.CustomerAssetTag,
        customerDeviceID = d.CustomerDeviceID
    }
}
```

However, EF will not allow you to nest these, and will complain that it cannot convert the nested extension method to SQL.

A work around for this can be to perform the transform in memory, rather than in SQL:

```cs
public static Model ToModel(this PTS_MODELS model)
{
    return new Model()
    {
        ModelID = model.ModelID,
        Name = model.Name,
        Make = new Make()
        {
            MakeID = model.PTS_MAKES.MakeID,
            Name = model.PTS_MAKES.Name
        }
    };
}

public static IEnumerable<CustomerDevice> ToCustomerDevice(this IQueryable<PTT_CUSTOMER_DEVICES> devices)
{
    return devices
        .Include(d => d.PTS_MODELS.PTS_MAKES)
        .AsEnumerable() // Evaulate everything that follows in memory
        .Select(d => new CustomerDevice
        {
            customerAssetTag = d.CustomerAssetTag,
            customerDeviceID = d.CustomerDeviceID,
            Model = d.PTS_MODELS.ToModel()
        });
}
```

Since you are now returning an `IEnumerable<>` any further `Where()` conditions will be evaluated in memory, rather than in SQL, so its important that `ToCustomerDevice()` is your last call.

Comment: This worked beautifully!  I would have never thought to do the conversion in memory like that.  You just made my life a thousand times easier.

Answer (score 0):

If those tables have a common base class or implement the same interface you can do it.

To make it simple assume I have a `IQueryable<string> names`. I can sort it like this:

```
IQueryable<string> sorted = names.OrderBy(name => name);
```

But if I want to keep this particular sort to use later I can do this:

```
Func<IQueryable<string>, IQueryable<string>> orderBy = q => q.OrderBy(x => x);
```

Now to call it I just pass any `IQueryable<string>` in:

```
IQueryable<string> sorted = orderBy(names);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a constructor for `Model` that takes a `CustomerDevice`? (what ever the entity is for `PTT_CUSTOMER_DEVICES`:

```
public Model(CustomerDevice d) {
    ModelID = d.PTS_MODELS.ModelID;
    Name = d.PTS_MODELS.Name;
    Make = new Make() {
        MakeID = d.PTS_MODELS.PTS_MAKES.MakeID,
        Name = d.PTS_MODELS.PTS_MAKES.Name
    };
}
```

Then you could just call that constructor in the LINQ:

```
Model = new Model(d),
```

Comment: Thank for the feedback, but unfortunately this doesn't work because LINQ to entities only accepts parameterless constructors.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think about that. I think you should look into LINQKit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Expression:

```
public static Expression<Func<PTT_CUSTOMER_DEVICES, CustomerDevice>>
            CustomerDeviceExpression = d =>
                new CustomerDevice
                {
                    customerAssetTag = d.CustomerAssetTag,
                    customerDeviceID = d.CustomerDeviceID,

                    Model = new Model()
                    {
                        ModelID = d.PTS_MODELS.ModelID,
                        Name = d.PTS_MODELS.Name,
                        Make = new Make()
                        {
                            MakeID = d.PTS_MODELS.PTS_MAKES.MakeID,
                            Name = d.PTS_MODELS.PTS_MAKES.Name
                        }
                    }
                 };
```

Then:

```
list = context.PTT_CUSTOMER_DEVICES
            .Include(...)
            .Select(CustomerDeviceExpression)...
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.